# Работа с Modbus RTU протоколом с помощью jamod

Tags: java, com-порт, modbus

У меня стоит задача брать данные с регистров контроллера ДГУ, ок примерно понял как открывать соединение с com-портом(rs-232 интерфейс), но встал вопрос, каким методом можно извлечь данные с регистров, на их сайте нашел пример, но там вовсе регистры не указываются. А мне надо чтобы я обратился к контроллеру по регистрам и он в ответ мне вернул параметры ДГУ. И как я потом это смогу протестировать не подключаясь к ДГУ контроллеру ?

Comment: Какие данные Вы смогли получить от контроллера? Просто состояния регистров будут отражены в соответствующих разрядах "сообщения". Какой байт (и бит) сообщения за что отвечает - отражено в таблице, которую Вы показывали.

Comment: Возможно, поиск поанглоязычной версии так же будет полезен: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rs-232+java

Comment: Дело в том что сейчас я не могу к ДГУ подключиться(делаю работу удаленно) придется тестировать у себя на ПК и отправлять заказчику, в How to есть пример и там они используют метод res = (ReadInputRegistersResponse) trans.getResponse(); и потом в for они используют метод getRegisterValue который возвращает int

Comment: Выглядит как то, что нужно. Я думаю, Вы уже делаете всё правильно. Получайте числа, сопоставляйте их с таблицей и выводите (или что требуется по задаче?) с соответствующими подписями.

Comment: Ок, я вас понял, спасибо большое!